# Python - Choose a dictionary in list which key is closer to a global value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries of images resolutions:

```
[
{'ratio': 1.7777777777777777, 'pixels': 230400, 'key': 'hor_640x360'}, 
{'ratio': 2.1006711409395975, 'pixels': 46637, 'key': 'hor_313x149'}, 
{'ratio': 2.1006711409395975, 'pixels': 746192, 'key': 'hor_1252x596'}
]
```

I need to choose the dictionary which ratio is closer to `1.77672955975` (that is the result of `float(565) / float(318)`) and, if the ratio is equal, the one with the most pixels. In other words I need to choose the biggest image from the list which, once resized and cropped to 565x318, will need less cropping.

I was thinking about sorting the list 2 times, the first time based on pixels and the second one based on which has the result of `abs(ratio - (float(565) / float(318)))` smaller. In this way on the top would remain the one with the most pixels and the closest ratio match. But how to do the sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`min(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=super#min) for that with a `key`:

```
matching_dic = min(dicts,key=lambda x:(abs(1.77672955975-x['ratio']),-x['pixels']))
```

resulting into:

```
>>> min(dicts,key=lambda x:(abs(1.77672955975-x['ratio']),-x['pixels']))
{'key': 'hor_640x360', 'pixels': 230400, 'ratio': 1.7777777777777777}
```

The idea is that the `key`: `lambda x:(abs(1.77672955975-x['ratio']),-x['pixels'])` will for each dictionary calculate the difference between your given ratio (here `1.77672955975`) and the `'ratio'` of this dictionary. We return a tuple (with `-x['pixels']` as second element for *tie-breaking* (kudos to @MosesKoledoye for spotting that).

Comment: If the ratio can't be negative (which I think is the case), you can simply use `x['ratio']` alone.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: but you have to calculate the *difference*: the difference can be negative.

Comment: Ah yes. You'll need `'pixels'` to break ties tho.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: apparently I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution for sorting by multiple attributes is to use tuples, because tuples get sorted by their elements.

```
keyfunc= lambda r:(abs(r['ratio']-1.77672955975), -r['pixels'])
print(min(resolutions, key=keyfunc))
```

Comment: Which should be equivalent to: `keyfunc = lambda r: (-abs(r['ratio'] - 1.77672955975), r['pixels']) print(max(resolutions, key=keyfunc))`